# Instantiate Error in Eclipse in calendar java code

Tags: java, eclipse

The error showing is:- Cannot instantiate the type SpinnerTimeStopped

```
enter code here    SpinnerTimeStopped spinnerTimeStopped = new SpinnerTimeStopped();
```

after new, SpinnerTimeStopped() is showing the above error even after importing the required jar files, with this import also, how to resolve the error or how to instantiate, any code change, can anybody preffer?

> Blockquote <"import guikit.TrinitiCalendar.TableMouseHandler.SpinnerTimeStopped;">

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a generally known Java library. If there is neither source code nor Javadoc nor any other documentation available, you should consider using some other library.

Answer (score 0):

Try using full qualified name :

```
guikit.TrinitiCalendar.TableMouseHandler.SpinnerTimeStopped spinnerTimeStopped = new SpinnerTimeStopped();`
```

If fails in this case then your eclipse is not able to locate the library.

See your build path configurations.  Otherwise go for another library as told by laune.